# How to save card with Stripe 3ds?

Tags: stripe-payments

I find that I can save a 3ds source for future use, but its only for single use. If I want to use 3ds but allow allow customer to save this card for future use many times, isit impossible to do so?

I used

`stripe.customers.createSource`

to save the source to the customer, then I tried to use it once, it works, but 2nd time fails with

> The source you provided is not in a chargeable state

Answer (score 1):

I covered Sources versus Cards conceptually in my answer to your other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51338279/1606729

A 3D Secure Source is created from a Card Source. This is something you do client-side based on whether the card supports (or even requires) 3D Secure as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/three-d-secure#check-requirement). Then you can use this new Source for the charge through 3D Secure.

Since the 3D Secure Source is single-use though, you want to keep the original Card Source too for future charges.

The flow is something like this:

1. Create a Card Source client-side `src_123`
2. Check if the Card Source requires/supports 3D Secure
3. If not, send the source id `src_123` to your server and save that Source on a customer to charge it now/in the future.
4. If yes, create a 3D Secure Source client-side `src_ABC`.
5. Have the customer complete 3D Secure verification which involves a redirect to their bank
6. Send the 3D Secure source id `src_ABC` to your server as it is ready to be charged
7. Save the original Card Source on the Customer too for future payments. This source id `src_123` is available on the 3D Secure Source under `three_d_secure[card]`.